# Group actions as colimit of torsors?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, category-theory

I'm learning group theory and I know a little bit about category theory(Mac Lane ch1-3,but have not appreciated what a colimit is).

I know a group action can be viewed as a functor from a group as a one-element category to $Set$. And I also know the statement of so-called co-Yoneda theorem,which roughly says any Set-valued functor is a colimit of representable functors. Furthermore,if I understand it correctly,the only representable functors in this setting are torsors(roughly,group action acting on this group viewed as a set,see [torsor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/torsor)).

I want to learn that,what's the meaning of co-Yoneda theorem in this example of group action?(roughly,any group action can be viewed as a colimit of "torsors". here "torsors" should be realized as whatever it should be in the co-Yoneda theorem.) Or,I should say I have no idea how to transform it into the group theory language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A group can be viewed as a one-object category where all arrows are isomorphisms. (Few categorists would say "one-element category".)  Concretely, given a group $G$, we can make a category $\mathcal{G}$ with one object, call it $*$ though what it is is completely irrelevant, and $\text{Hom}(*,*) = G$.  $id$ corresponds to the unit of $G$ and $\circ$ corresponds to the multiplication of $G$.  A functor $F : \mathcal{G} \to \mathbf{Set}$ gives a group action. The one-object gets mapped to a set $X=F(*)$ and each arrow $g$ in $\mathcal{G}$ (i.e. each element of the group $G$) gets mapped to a function $F(g) : X \to X$.  The functor laws $F(id) = id$ and $F(f \circ g) = Ff \circ  Fg$, say exactly that $F$ is a group homomorphism from $G$ to the automorphism group $X \to X$, i.e. $F$ is a group action.

Generally, a representable functor, is a functor $H : \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Set}$ for some category $\mathcal{C}$ that is naturally isomorphic to a $\text{Hom}$ functor, i.e. $H \cong \text{Hom}(Z, -)$ where the object $Z$ is said to represent the functor $H$.  In our case, there's only one object so up to isomorphism the only representable functor is $\text{Hom}(*,-)$.  This functor corresponds to $G$ acting on itself.  Not looking at things only up to isomorphism, we have that a natural transformation $\tau : H \to \text{Hom}(*,-)$ is a natural transformation with only one component since $\mathcal{G}$ has only one object and which concretely looks like $g\cdot\tau(x) = \tau(H(g)(x))$ where $g\cdot g'$ is the multiplication of the group, i.e. composition in $\mathcal{G}$.  For it to be a natural isomorphism it would have an inverse which satisfied $\tau^{-1}(g\cdot g') = H(g)(\tau^{-1}(g'))$.  Combining these we can define the action of $H$ on arrows via $H(g)(x) = \tau^{-1}(g\cdot\tau(x))$.

The [co-Yoneda lemma](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/co-Yoneda+lemma) is the following statement $$KX \cong \int^{C:\mathcal{C}} \text{Hom}(C^-, X)\times KC^+ \cong \text{Hom}(-,X)\star K \cong \text{Lan}_{Id}K(X)$$ natural in $X$ where $\int^C$ denotes a [coend](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/end), $\star$ denotes the [weighted colimit](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/weighted+colimit), and $\text{Lan}_J D$ is the left [Kan extension](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kan+extension) of $D$ along $J$.  Incidentally, the regular Yoneda lemma is $$KX \cong \int_{C:\mathcal{C}} \mathbf{Set}(\text{Hom}(C^-,X), KC^+) \cong \{\text{Hom}(-,X),K\} \cong \text{Ran}_{Id}K(X)$$ where $\int_C$ denotes the end, the brackets denote the weighted limit, and $\text{Ran}_J D$ is the right Kan extension of $D$ along $J$.  The superscript $+$ and $-$ are my own variation of notation to keep track of whether the bound variable $C$ is in a covariant or contravariant position.  You are probably not familiar with any of these concepts as they are not "beginning of the book" material.  Surprisingly and unfortunately, (co)ends and weighted (co)limits are often nowhere in the book.  This is surprising as these notions are critical for enriched category theory (suggesting they are more natural than (conical) (co)limits), and they *dramatically* simplify calculations.  Conical (co)limits can be expressed as (co)ends over functors that only use the bound variable covariantly.  With my notation, it looks like $\int^C DC^+ \cong \text{Colim}(D)$ (one of the benefits of tracking variance).

In $\mathbf{Set}$, it is possible to express weighted colimits as (conical) colimits indexed by the [category of elements](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+of+elements) of the weighting functor.  I'm not going to go into detail about the category of elements, since I just want to have a concrete expression of the particular colimit in $\mathbf{Set}$, so I will just say that we get the following rewriting of a coend: $$\int^{C:\mathcal{C}} WC^-\times HC^+ \cong \int^{E:\text{el}W} H(\pi(E^+)) \cong \text{Colim}(H \circ \pi)$$ where $\pi : \text{el}W \to \mathcal{C}$ is the codomain projection of the category of elements.  When both $H$ and $W$ are $\mathbf{Set}$-valued, we can swap them about (which results in indexing over the opposite category) and so choosing $W = F$ and $H = \text{Hom}(-,X)$ we get $$FY \cong \int^{E:(\text{el}F)^{op}} \text{Hom}(\pi^{op}(E^+),Y) \cong \int^{(A,B):(\text{el}F)^{op}} \text{Hom}(A^+,Y) \cong \text{Colim}(\text{Hom}(-,Y) \circ \pi^{op})$$ which is to say, $F$ is a colimit of representables.  In our case, $\text{el}F$ has an object for each element of $X = F(*)$, hence "category of elements", and an arrow from $x\in X$ to $y\in X$ exactly when $y = F(g)(x)$ for some $g\in G$.

In general, a colimit in $\mathbf{Set}$ of a functor $D : \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Set}$, is made by first forming a coproduct (i.e. disjoint union) of $D$ over all the objects $C$ of $\mathcal{C}$, giving $\coprod_{C\in \text{Ob}(\mathcal{C})}DC$ whose elements look like pairs of an object $C$ of $\mathcal{C}$ and an element of $DC$.  From there we quotient it by the equivalence relation which for $(C, x)$ and $(C', y)$ in $\coprod_{C\in\text{Ob}(\mathcal{C})} DC$, we have 
$$(C, x) \sim (C', y) \iff (\exists f:C \to C'. D(f)(x) = y)\lor(\exists g:C' \to C. D(g)(y) = x)$$
so $\text{Colim}(D) \cong (\coprod_{C\in\text{Ob}(\mathcal{C})} DC)/\!\sim$.
In our case, it works out to be $$FY \cong \left(\coprod_{x \in F(*)}\text{Hom}(*, Y)\right)/\!\sim\ \cong (F(*)\times\text{Hom}(*,Y))/\!\sim\ = (X\times\text{Hom}(*,Y))/\!\sim$$ which, at the only object of $\mathcal{G}$ will be $$X = F(*) \cong (X\times \text{Hom}(*,*))/\!\sim\ = (X\times G)/\!\sim$$ where 
$$\begin{align}(x,g_1) \sim (y,g_2) & \iff \exists g \in G.x = F(g)(y) \land g_1\cdot g = g_2 \\& \iff x = F(g_1^{-1}\cdot g_2)(y) \\& \iff F(g_1)(x) = F(g_2)(y)\end{align}$$
There's a touch of subtlety here.  The $\exists g\in G.x = F(g)(y)$ comes from the $\exists f: C \to C'$ part of the general definition, where here an arrow of $\text{el}F$ from $x \to y$ was defined to be a $g$ such that $F(g)(x) = y$.  But wait! That's still not the same thing.  What's happening is that we indexed over the *opposite* category of the category of elements, so an arrow $x \to y$ in $(\text{el}F)^{op}$ is an arrow $y \to x$ in $\text{el}F$ which is a $g$ such that $F(g)(y) = x$.  The hardest part of categorical calculations is making sure you keep your variances straight, and this probably took me the most time of all of this.

The action of this functor on arrows is $$((X\times\text{Hom}(*,g))/\sim)([(x,g')]) = [(x, g\cdot g')] = [(F(g')(x), g)]$$

To verify, we have $\tau : F \to (X\times\text{Hom}(*,-))/\!\sim$ via $\tau(x) = [(x,1)]$ and $\tau^{-1}([(x,g)]) = F(g)(x)$.  We need to show that these are group action homomorphisms and that they are inverses.  For the former for $\tau$ we need to show that $[(F(g)(x),1)] = [(x,g)]$ which is true because $F(1)(F(g)(x)) = F(g)(x)$.  This is also what's needed to show $\tau^{-1}$ is well-defined (i.e. it doesn't depend on the representative chosen) and to show that $\tau$ and $\tau^{-1}$ are inverses, so we are done.

Comment: Amazing,I hadn't expected a so long and elaborate answer! Thank you very much. But I still have problems:1.what's the meaning of the isomorphism between X and (X*G)/~,does that simply mean bijection between sets?(I suppose here (X*G)/~ is a set.)  2.While after a few lines,you constructed a homomorphism between F and (X*G)/~,so is (X*G)/~ a functor or a set? 3.what is D in our case?and before that,you wrote take the disjoint union of DC,but after a few lines it becomes disjoint union of D?

Comment: I'll change the notation for the disjoint union over $D$.  I was a bit worried about it and it seems it was justified.  For us, $DE = \text{Hom}(\pi^{op}(E),*)$ where $E$ is from the category of elements.  It may make more sense to view the objects/arrows of $\text{el}F$ as pairs of objects/arrows from $\mathcal{G}$ and another component which $\pi$ ignores, i.e. $D(Y,Z) = \text{Hom}(Y,*)$, so $D$ is just like $\text{Hom}(-,*)$ just with an extra parameter that is ignored.

Comment: As for $(X\times G)/\sim$, what's happening is (co)limits in functor categories are calculated pointwise.  In other words, a parameterized (co)limit in $\mathbf{Set}$ can be lifted to a (co)limit of functors.  So the $Y$ in the expression for $FY$ is still there, but I calculated it at the single object $Y=*$, however the action on arrows is still present and is $\text{Hom}(*,g)(g') = g \cdot g'$.  I was wondering about how to be clearer about this and I have an idea now that may work, so I'll tweak that part.

Comment: Can I understand this way:the preimage of f of each point of X induces a partition on $X*G$,where the action is viewed as f: $X*G$$->$G,and this partition defines a quotient object,on which we can define a functor naturally isomorphic to the original one? this seems to me that co-Yoneda lemma is something like uncurrying and Yoneda like currying.

Comment: Yes, given an element $y \in X$, $\{ (x,g)\in X\times G\ |\ F(g)(x) = y \}$ is the equivalence class that represents $y$. As for the action, $f : X\times G \to G$ is not the right type for a $G$-action, so I'm not sure what you mean. Essentially, if we always normalize to the $[(x,1)]$ representative, then the action of $g$ is $[(F(g)(x),1)]$ which is clearly equivalent to $F$. I'm also not quite sure what you're saying about currying/uncurrying, though there *is* a curry/uncurry like relationship *between* weighted limits/colimits generally, and Yoneda/co-Yoneda particularly.

Comment: and the reason I didn't work out these myself may be that i'm easily got lost in logical details.. For the more theoretical part of your post,i think perhaps i'm not well-prepared to go into,but once i'm ready i'll go back to see your post~

Comment: Yeah, that's about what I expected, and I even considered recommending seeing how it goes and then coming back later. Some of it is geared more toward being a guide post/reminder than an answer.  For example, you should *definitely* learn about (co)ends and weighted (co)limits but probably not right now. It's also not clear to me if this example is the best one. A related, more accessible, yet perhaps more interesting example is we can take the (co)limit of the group actions as functors! The colimit is the set of orbits; the limit is the set of points fixed by all of $G$.